# How to prove the difference of two regular complex Borel measures is regular?

Tags: measure-theory

This is on page 130 of Rudin's real & complex analysis. The book says that this is easy to see, but I'm having trouble proving it.

Suppose $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are two regular complex Borel measures. For inner regularity, given $E$ and $\epsilon >0$, we have $K_1,K_2\subset E$ such that $|\mu_1|(K_1)+\epsilon >|\mu_1|(E)$ and $|\mu_2|(K_2)+\epsilon >|\mu_2|(E)$. I want to use $K_1\cup K_2$ for $|\mu_1 + \mu_2|$ (consider sum of the measures instead of difference), but it does not seem to work.

Is this technique on the right track?

Answer (score 5):

**(1)** Show that if $\mu$ is a regular complex Borel measure, then so is $-\mu$.

**(2)** Now use the fact that the sum of two regular complex Borel measures is a regular complex Borel measure (which you know how to prove).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was actually confused about (2), but I think I get it now. (1) should be easy. For (2), Given $E$ and $\epsilon >0$, we have $|\mu_1|(E)-|\mu_1|(K_1)<\epsilon/2$ for a compact set $K_1\subset E$ and $|\mu_2|(E)-|\mu_2|(K_2)<\epsilon/2$ for a compact $K_2\subset E$, by regularity of $\mu_1,\mu_2$. We can assume $K_1=K_2=K$ since we can simply take the union if they're not equal. Now add the two inequalities and do some manipulations we get $|\mu_1+\mu_2|(E-K)\le (|\mu_1|+|\mu_2|)(E-K)<\epsilon$ and the result follows. Is this right?

Comment: @D.Huang Yes, it looks great! Don't forget to upvote and accept answers which you like. You can upvote by clicking the arrow pointing upward to the left of the answer and accept by clicking the tick mark just below the arrow pointing downward to the left of the answer.  (It's only possible to accept answers to your own questions but you can upvote any answer you see on this website that you like!) The point of accepting an answer is to let other users know that you're satisfied that your question has been answered (of course, you don't have to upvote or accept answers but it's encouraged).